# How to type column vectors in MathJax?

Tags: vector, mathjax

I know I can use `bmatrix` in MathJax, but for vector the syntax looks a bit verbose. Isn't there a more compact way for inputing just vectors than writing:

`$\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \cr 3 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 2 \cr 2 \end{bmatrix} \right) \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 4 \cr 4 \end{bmatrix}  =0$`

[image]

Comment: `\cr` is not latex syntax, it should be `\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank you. It seems that in MathJax It works (and generate same output) both with \cr and \\.

Comment: yes cr works in latex as well (it is the tex primitive that underlies `\\ ` but it's still incorrect even though it happens to typeset without error) . It is not clear whether you want a more compact _output_ (eg from smallmatrix or shortstack) or whether you just want a less verbose markup (you could define a llocal command)

Comment: remember that mathjax does not use latex and is thus unrelated here. the `smallmatrix` env is supported my mathjax though)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question to make clear I mean a more compact way to _write_  column vectors..

Comment: Dear all, as suggested on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) I use this space to express my disagreement for the closure of this question. While the linked help page doesn't explicit name "MathJax" it well refers to "related software and tools". According to a [well-received answer on an other topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378734/43800) "[MathJax] renders various mathematical markup languages, notably a language that is essentially the math subset of LaTeX syntax". The implementation may be different, but the usage level is the same.

Comment: (continuation)

There is even a tag on this site "MathJax" with over 180 questions.

I do believe that MathJax should be considered as on topic on this site, with the invitation to well define that the question refers to it to receive pertinent answers (but isn't the same with different TeX distributions and engines? Tags for this are really useful)

Comment: mathjax specific questions are (and I think should be) off topic, but your question (and my answer) apply equally to latex so this should not have been closed. I have voted to re-open

Comment: @Antonello mathjax isn't like a different tex engine (say pdftex instead of xetex) or different distribution (texlive or miktex) it simply doesn't use tex at all and apart from a very thin surface syntax designed to look latex-like works in completely different ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a lot of these you can define a local command (which would also work in mathjax)

```
 \newcommand\mycolv[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}
```

then you just need

```
\mycolv{1\\3}  and \mycolv{4\\4}
```

Comment: Thank you. To note that the new command works even on successive MathJax cells (in the same document).