# LaTeX in Blogger

Tags: online

I have looked on the web and found some unsatisfactory solutions to getting LaTeX working on Blogger. Ideally I wouldn't have to switch to Wordpress, however, if the time comes, I can migrate.

> I am wondering if there is a good way to get this working that does not require program or extension installed on my computer. Furthermore I would like the rendering to be viewable on Win, Mac, and Linux.

I considered jsMath, but for some reason cannot find how to get this working on Blogger.

Additional features that would be ideal is the ability to render the LaTeX using packages on my machine, and even better, allowing me to compose a document in the LaTeX front end of my choice and render/upload though command line.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Latex on blogspot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13865/how-to-use-latex-on-blogspot)

Comment: (see the discussion on the linked question to understand why I'm voting to close the *earlier* of the two questions on the same topic)

Answer (score 7):

consider this: http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: It appears that this requires mathjax to be installed on the server, and thus on my computer that I am using to edit the blog. Right?

Comment: It does need to be installed on the server, but from what I see in the documentation, not on the computer you're using to edit the blog. And installing it is just a matter of uploading some files and editing your HTML template to include the script, which I would think Blogger should allow you to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can copy a code snippet from [this post](http://mnnttl.blogspot.com/2011/02/latex-on-blogger.html) and paste it in Blogger template. Simple, easy, and powerful. It uses the power of [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) (as mentioned above but I cannot add a comment) which works on all modern browsers.

Comment: The link “this post” does not work any more.

Comment: Try [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110412103745/http://mnnttl.blogspot.com/2011/02/latex-on-blogger.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you use WordPress based site, consider my [GFormula plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/gformula/1989026?ref=straightforward) to compile and embed LaTeX images. Also you can set image dimensions for compiled image, background and foreground colors.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If this is your own product – which it seems to be –, it would be considered good style to mention this in your answer. (In your [other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129/embedding-latex-equations-into-a-webpage/51168#51168) as well.)

Answer (score 0):

In January, I tried out mathtex2.js from watchmath.com and it worked.

However, I decided to turn off LaTeX rendering, and as I checked today, the watchmath.com site was down, and the name of the script has changed to mathtex3.js.

Maybe [this link](http://a2mstats.blogspot.com/2010/04/writing-equation-in-blogger-using-latex.html) helps.