# How to convert LaTeX in html for Blogger

Tags: html

I am trying to embed formulas in Blogger. My system is OpenSuse, and I create a LaTeX file for my formulas, say `filename`. In order to convert the LaTeX code into an html code I run:

```
pdflatex filename
latex2html filename.tex
```

This produces a directory with all sorts of files. It appears that the file containing the html code is `images.pl` (is this correct?)

But when I insert it into the post in Blogger (in html mode of writing) and save it, it does not produce the desired formula but instead simply presents the code.

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps some example code might be helpful? What are you pasting into blogger?

Comment: This is, btw, a duplicate of an [existing question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/latex-in-blogger).

Comment: @Juan: your link is circular

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it. I got confused since both questions have the exact same title!

Comment: @Juan: Is not really a duplicate, because this question here is actually about latex2html.

Answer (score 3):

This question sounds like [mathtran](http://www.mathtran.org/) would be a better solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a bit confused about how all these things can be put together. Most likely, `images.pl` doesn't contain any HTML but some scripting code to generate your images. Somewhere in the directory created by `latex2html` you should be able to find image files (maybe some `png` or `gif` files) which are the ones you should upload to blogger and insert just as regular images in compose (no need to go into html mode).

Now, all this is probably an overkill if you only want to create some images from equations in order to include in your blog posts. As [Taco Hoekwater](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3968/latex-in-blogger/3973#3973) has already suggested, you can use other online services to generate your images and then insert those in your blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers! Juan, I indeed misinterpreted the role played by images.pl Anyway, I indeed uploaded the gif files and this works well except that it does not fit the color of the background, and that I cannot embed the formula as a part of a text.

So the question remains: how do I embed a latex code in a post in blogger?

For example, how do I embed the text

```
Newton's 3-rd law $\boldsymbol{F}=\dot{\boldsymbol{p}}$ is not invariant under Lorentz transformations...
```

in such a way that the formula is converted automatically to html?

Comment: You should edit the original question or/and comment on Juan’s answer instead of posting an “answer”. For your second question, you should really refer to the [other ”LaTeX in Blogger” question.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/latex-in-blogger)

Comment: Following the instruction there did not produce the required result, but perhaps I am missing something. Playing with the templates there is a little bit scary because I'm afraid to make `irreversible' changes in a platform which I do not fully understand. So... I'm stuck...

Comment: Problem solved! on-line converter can be find here: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php