# Tex like formatting on blog posts

Tags: formatting, online

When I write reports for school I usually use an IEEE formatted LaTex document these days because I feel like it just looks so much better then anything I can seem to do in Word. I have a blog and would like to be able to make my posts look as high quality as my reports do, but I just don't know how to do it, is there a similar way to format blog posts to look like Latex (or shoot even use latex). I would like to avoid simply creating an "image" as that doesn't seem very search engine friendly.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas how to format a blog post (I use blogger at this point) so it looks as high quality as latex? (I would love it if i could simply type in latex code and generate an actual blog post).

I'm really not sure if this is the best place to post this question but since I am trying to duplicate Latex quality format I thought I would try here first, hoping someone else has ran into a similar stype.

Comment: check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/latex-in-blogger

Comment: There's a big difference between: a) web posts that *look* like TeX output (with kerning and everything), b) web posts that look as good on the web as TeX does on paper, and c) using (La)TeX markup to produce web pages.  Not all of (a) is good: things prepared for paper (even as PDFs to be read online) do not automatically look good in a browser; (b) is more about design and browser capability.  For (c), take a look at the link that Yiannis mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out tex4ht: http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html

You could write your posts in latex, run tex4ht to produce a html file, and then paste the code into Blogger.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to type in tex code and output HTML code, I would recommend a package like HeVeA, which I've had (some) luck with. [this paper](http://student.johnpdaigle.com/adaptpaper.php) was generated with HeVeA from LaTeX. Don't judge me on content, guys, I wrote that a LONG time ago.

A major shortcoming of HeVeA is that if you use TikZ/PGF, it can't convert the images to a web displayable format. But as far as I know, nothing can--at least not straight from the code.

Comment: Actually, TikZ can convert TikZ/PGF to web displayable content.  Using tex4ht and the pgfsys-tex4ht driver, it converts pictures to SVG (text is a little dubious, but that's more due to the limitations of SVG than TikZ).  I've found this remarkably useful in producing SVGs.

Comment: I'll have to check this out. If this occurs inline than it's the coolest thing ever.

Comment: Error 404 as of today

Answer (score 2):

There is a interesting project called *"TEX line breaking algorithm in JavaScript"* by Bram Stein which might be applicable here. You can find it [here](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/typeset/). Combine that with the [Hyphenator.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/) and some heavy-handed CSS, and you could have a somewhat OK-ish looking text-blocks in (X)HTML.

Doesn't cover the math-mode though, AFAIK.

Comment: It's more than applicable, especially if SEO is involved. Runtime hyphenation (hyphenator.js inserts soft hyphens at runtime) is the only reliable way to do pretty line-breaking while maintaining word integrity in the actual source.

Answer (score 1):

For 2019 and beyond, possibly:

https://katex.org/