# TeX typesetting algorithms for web sites

Tags: typography, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tex like formatting on blog posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/tex-like-formatting-on-blog-posts)

I wonder if there are any solutions for using TeX typesetting algorithms for web sites publishing to make pages as beautiful and readable as TeX documents. Maybe through CSS or some scripts?

For instance I hate how justified alignment is done on web pages and how ugly it is compared to the wonderful job by TeX.

Comment: You can ask LaTeX for the hyphenation information about each word. Then you can use the unicode character or HTML entity for a word-break, most browsers recognize them. Concerning the LaTeX part, the command `\showhyphens` prints the hyphenation of a given words in the log. This is not a complete solution, just a hint how (La)TeX could help.

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6795/1410) answer.