# How to use LaTeX on blogspot?

Tags: online

I'm trying to use LaTeX on my blog, but I could not figure out how. Has anyone done it before? Any feedback or related information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to give us more detail, for example whether you are using a hosted blog, the blog software and version, _etc._

Comment: @Joseph: Presumably blogspot.

Comment: Very much related: [LaTeX in Blogger](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3797/1235) (possible duplicate?).

Comment: @Hendrik: they are very much related, but the related question hasn't been marked as answered.  Now that mathjax has a CDN, the top-voted answer in the related question is outdated (and was incomplete anyway).  So if Chan is successful with this, I the older question should be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Matthew: That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Jasper: Because it was in the title of the question.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I would say use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).  It's a AJAX engine for LaTeX syntax that now is distributed by a CDN so you don't have to upload a single file to your blogspot account.

To enable MathJax, just drop in

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/latest/MathJax.js">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
 extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
 jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
 tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
     displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
 },
 "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
});
</script>
```

after the header (`<head>`) in the Blogger template (Design→Edit HTML→Edit Template).

Googling "install mathjax blogspot" led me to a page on the Web Applications StackExchange: [MathJax on Blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/mathjax-on-blogger).

See the MathJax pages for more information about configuring and using it.

Comment: @Chan: did you end up doing it this way?  Did it work?  If so, you can click the green check and we'll merge the older question into this one.

Comment: This helped me get $\LaTeX$ on my blog, thank you. What more, the same trick works for _comments_ as well, provided they appear on the same page as the post!

Comment: The page of instruction pointed is now unavailable:
"El blog se ha eliminado. Lo sentimos, el blog de mnnttl.blogspot.com se ha eliminado. Esta dirección no está disponible para blogs nuevos."

Comment: @Jeremy: updated the link.  There's now a page on StackExchange to refer to.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks! Although... "The server at www.mathjax.org is taking too long to respond."...

Comment: FYI I tried using the above solution with blogspot's dynamic views and had trouble rendering the equations.  When I switched to a standard template for the blog, the equations rendered.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang If I want every mathematical expression in blue, what should I add?

Comment: @OLSAY: That's a question to ask the MathJax folks.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ worked perfect on my page http://www.molympiad.ml/2017/08/mathematics-and-youth-magazine-problems-456.html

Comment: For those who are looking for a similar configuration but with the latest MathJax (version 3): https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153527/196564

Comment: @raf: Thank you for updating my 10-year-old answer!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It's my pleasure! I personally felt the necessity of adding an updated answer. As I said in the answer: "People like me prefer getting a solution directly than reading the long documentations and end up coming here through Google search." Btw, it would be a great help if you kindly check my config and give feedback: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57650810#57650810