# Handwritten math formula recognition to LaTeX

Tags: latex-misc

I am looking for a way to integrate handwritten math formula recognition (to LaTex) in my app. A good example of this can be seen here
http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/equation.html?locale=default

Any suggestions on where I can start or an available api to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Related is [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1654/15717). Have a look [For browser math rendering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62975/15717). Unrelated on windows OS [Math Input Panel](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/use-math-input-panel-to-write-and-correct-math-equations).

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. Not sure if [this math rendering](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/2013/Recognition.png) is any good:-)