# Running pdflatex inside web page

Tags: pdftex, online

I have already read [How to incorporate TeX into a website?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/how-to-incorporate-tex-into-a-website)
There is a sketch of the way of compiling to PDF from the web page, with limitations.

Are there any easy to use methods of achieving this goal? A few years later there should be some standard tool, however I haven't found it yet...

Comment: This is either a duplicate or too vague to be answerable. If you want the same thing as asked there, it is just a duplicate and if there is now a better answer, it would be best placed in linked Q&A. Plus, the answers there mention numerous `standard tool`s, so it is not at all clear what exactly you hope to find. It isn't even clear which answer you are looking at since there are many. If you don't want what is asked for there, what do you want? What is supposed to happen to the PDF? What is it meant to be compiled from? What at all are you trying to do?

Comment: @cfr I have in mind @xport answer. Five years later there should be more standard tools, than creating the code from the ground level. In this  sense I am asking for a `standard' methods.

Comment: `should` in what sense? Are you volunteering to provide them?

Comment: Note that you cannot do this simply for a website at all - not in the sense you want to do it. You need a server with an installation of TeX and the process you use needs to take account of the security implications of compilation. In truth, your question is off-topic in this case. You need to ask on a forum concerned with setting up and securing a web-server etc. But it would be quite unreasonable to expect a `standard method` for this, because so much will depend on the details of what you are doing, who will have access etc. It is always a trade-off: security vs. user features. Etc. etc.

Comment: If you want to run `pdflatex` on your server and display its output on a webpage (which I gather from your mention of @xport's answer from the other question), there is nothing here specific to TeX/LaTeX: you'd do exactly the kind of things you'd do for running an arbitrary program on your server and displaying its output on the webpage, with similar security considerations and all that. (If you want pdflatex to run inside the browser of the user viewing your webpage, that is another matter: probably [texlive.js](https://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/) is state-of-the-art, and it's slow.)

Comment: why do you want to use pdflatex here? The standard tool (eg as used in the math stackexchange site) is to use mathjax as suggested in several of the answers in the linked question. If you just mean running tex on the server and displaying the pdf that is purely a server config question unrelated to tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is because some advaned TeX tools are used and MathJax cannot support them.

Comment: Ok but if you just mean to run pdftex then it's the same issues as running any program on the server, there are not any tex-specific issues are there? But is the document dynamic, what is different from just serving the pdf that you generate  with pdftex offline?