# Displaying given TeX code for web application (HTML/Javascript)?

Tags: html, javascript

The title is pretty general but I have a bit of a specific question.

I'm given a database of TeX code. I'm not familiar with what sort of format it's in (LaTeX, KaTeX, etc.), I only understand that it is TeX form. Here are some examples:

Raw TeX:

```
Is there a number `a` such that `$\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^2 + ax + a + 3}{x^2 + x - 2}$` exists? If so, find the value of `a` and the value of the limit.
```

The same question in HTML:

```
<p> Is there a number <code>a</code> such that <code class='latex inline'>\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^2 + ax + a + 3}{x^2 + x - 2}</code> exists?
     If so, find the value of <code>a</code> and the value of the limit.</p>
```

I want to display this on my web application, but I'm having difficulties finding which library I'm supposed to use to render these in. I don't know where the `<code class='latex inline'>` comes from. Can anybody identify what TeX form it is and how to render them?

Comment: this is a javascript question so off topic here but search out the mathjax library.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because JavaScript libraries are off topic here (could be raised on stackoverflow) mathjax tag.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that may help:

[How to incorporate TeX into a website?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/how-to-incorporate-tex-into-a-website)

mathjax (used on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com)). See https://www.mathjax.org/, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ,

https://code.sololearn.com/WjCrAa4XhDJl/#html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed. I knew that, but thought I was on math stackexchange, where I spend more time than I do here.