# Installing LaTeX on a personal (externally hosted) web server to render images

Tags: installing, online

I have seen some similar questions but I admit I'm a newbie when it comes to cgi and general server setup and need some direction. I have a personal domain hosted on *yahoo.com* that I would like to install LaTeX on. I would like it so that it works in the following (or similar) way. Typing

`<img src="www.mysite.com/latex.cgi?{my formula}">`

will create a rendered gif that I may post on other websites, mainly forums without LaTeX support where I like to help others. Only basic packages are required for my uses (at least for now), things such as Tikz are not needed.

So is this very difficult to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This sounds more like a web server configuration issue that a TeX/LaTeX problem, so may be another forum is more appropriate.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Do you have a suggestion where I might post this? My thought is that setting up LaTeX in this way might be too specific a question for a general server type forum

Comment: using images for math on the web is so horrible:-) have you considered mathjax?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I looked at it, but it looks like that is best for a personal blog or something else where math is rendered on a local page. I need to be able to post the images on other websites

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129/15925 help?

Comment: The mathURL in the accepted answer there is more or less what I want to have automated. I have been, possibly inappropriately, been piggybacking off of a website codecogs.com which does what I need. For example: typing "http://codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dfrac{d}{dx} e^{x^2} = 2xe^{x^2}" gives: http://codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cdfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%20e%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D%20=%202xe%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D

Comment: You could also look at http://www.quicklatex.com/. If you really want to make the graphics yourself: I would make them locally and upload only the graphics to your domain. Installing and running a large program like latex on a server needs skills that you don't seem to have (me neither). E.g. how do you want to secure the server against misuses from others?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'd hope it wouldn't be too difficult to add a conditional or something similar where I can restrict the domains the images are being displayed on, much like the image sites which disable hotlinking. I would consider that approach if I wasn't linking 5-8 images in each post, and then fixing typos I don't realize would be a huge pain